# Proper file structure while developing several Azure DevOps custom tasks

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm developing 2 node.js-based tasks as contributions of my Azure DevOps extension. According to my experience, every task must be self-contained in terms of files and cannot depend on files brought by other contributions (correct?).

If I'm correct, what is the best practice in the situation below:

The source tree looks as below:

```
TaskA
  |___TaskA files
TaskB
  |___TaskB files
Common
  |___Common files
```

How can I package the "Common files" as a part of both tasks? Do I need to copy them to the TaskA and TaskB folders before creating my VSIX file or there is some creative way to cause the extension to deploy them to a common directory and then let the tasks' code "require" this common location?

Thank you in advance,
Moshe.

Comment: The most important private case of my question is the "node_modules" folder. Should it be duplicated for every task even if no difference exists or it can be common for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of "shared folders" between tasks in Azure Pipelines. It's your job to put all the files in the task folder prior to packaging.

You can use whatever script tech to copy the files to a dist folder prior to packaging. In the Azure DevOps Extension tasks [I used a trick in Typescript to always include the files in the `common` folder as part of the output](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-tasks/blob/26dd87f36770d346ea4bdbf9adf760f57d3c47b2/BuildTasks/tsconfig.v4.json#L11-L14).

I've seen others install the [common package from filesystem into the node_modules folder of the task packages.](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-artifact-caching-tasks/blob/master/make-util.js#L158) Example can be found in this project's `make-util.js`.